# How to understand @VIL in dalvik bycode

Tags: android, dalvik, ida

I use ida open classes.dex, and it show

```
CODE:00189570                 invoke-virtual                  {v0, v1, menu}, <void MenuInflater.inflate(int, ref) imp. @ _def_MenuInflater_inflate@VIL>
```

I don't understand the @VIL in the end of line, what's it?
the full code

```
//MainActivity.java
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

the full ida view

```
public boolean ro.rotry.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(
CODE:00189564       android.view.Menu menu)
CODE:00189564 this = v2
CODE:00189564 menu = v3
CODE:00189564                 .prologue_end
CODE:00189564                 .line 34
CODE:00189564                 invoke-virtual                  {this}, <ref MainActivity.getMenuInflater() imp. @ _def_MainActivity_getMenuInflater@L>
CODE:0018956A                 move-result-object              v0
CODE:0018956C                 const/high16                    v1, 0x7F0D0000
CODE:00189570                 invoke-virtual                  {v0, v1, menu}, <void MenuInflater.inflate(int, ref) imp. @ _def_MenuInflater_inflate@VIL>
CODE:00189576                 .line 35
CODE:00189576                 const/4                         v0, 1
CODE:00189578
CODE:00189578 locret:
CODE:00189578                 return                          v0
CODE:00189578 Method End
```

**update**

here is my [full android app code, https://github.com/roroco/try_the_complex/tree/understand-@VIL]

Comment: return v takes i and l as params ... shorcuts are alomst self-explanatory

Answer (score -1):

I find all methods in classes.dex has `/@[VIZL]+/`, I think it's very similar [roman number(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals), I guess @VIL means "at V(5)I(1)L(50) address", and in ida functions window, it exist @ZL, the "Z" means 0